# Round a value dependent on the first significant figure of the uncertainty

Tags: r, rounding

I am wondering how I would round a value dependent on the values uncertainty.

For example:

If the value is `0.2563` and the uncertainty on this value is `0.007423`. I would like to round the value to `0.256+/-0.007`.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and expected result based on that example.

Comment: related: [Report uncertainty: given a mean and the standard error, show only significant figures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53976847/4279)

Answer (score 4):

I think you can try

```
x=0.2563
y=0.007423
paste0(round(x,digits = 3),"+-",round(y,digits = 3))
#[1] "0.256+-0.007
```

Or with plus-minus character:

```
paste0(round(x,digits = 3),"\u00B1",round(y,digits = 3))
#[1] "0.256±0.007"
```

Answer (score 1):

What about a simple:

```
val <- x + c(-1,1)*y
val
[1] 0.248877 0.263723
round(val, digits = 4)
[1] 0.2489 0.2637
```

Or another way could be:

```
x + c(-1, 1)* round(y, 3)
[1] 0.2493 0.2633
```

I believe it depends on what level of precision do you need and what elements (`x` or `y`) can be or cannot be rounded.