# Report uncertainty: given a mean and the standard error, show only significant figures

Tags: python, statistics, uncertainty

The intent is to show the result of several observations without
unnecessary digits i.e., to display a value with the
number of significant digits that is consistent with a given
uncertainty.

For example, if computed `mean=123.45` and `err=0.0012345` then the
expected output may look like *123450 ± 1.2 (× 10<sup>-3</sup>)* where
the following rules are used:

1. the error always has one or two significant digits. Two if the first
   digit is `1` (ignoring the leading zeros)
2. the mean value is rounded to drop uncertain digits except for the
   last one (["stop the mean at the same decade as that of the *first* significant (non-zero) digit in the SEM"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.1034)). Trailing zeros are added to display the precision corresponding to the error if necessary.

How it might be used in Python:

```
import statistics

mean = statistics.mean(measurements)
err = statistics.stdev(measurements, mean) / len(measurements) ** 0.5
print("{} ± {} (×10<sup>{}</sup>)".format(*round_to_uncertainty(mean, err)))
```

The question is how to implement the `round_to_uncertainty(value,
uncertainty)` function expressing the rules 1 and 2 above.

Note: the terms error, uncertainty are used loosely in the
question. See [the Guide to the Expression of Uncertainty in Measurement (GUM)](https://www.bipm.org/en/publications/guides/gum.html). Here's a [related question for R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/46519/2530).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module could be used to manipulate the decimal representation of the numbers conveniently:

```
from decimal import Decimal

def round_to_uncertainty(value, uncertainty):
    # round the uncertainty to 1-2 significant digits
    u = Decimal(uncertainty).normalize()
    exponent = u.adjusted()  # find position of the most significant digit
    precision = (u.as_tuple().digits[0] == 1)  # is the first digit 1?
    u = u.scaleb(-exponent).quantize(Decimal(10)**-precision)

    # round the value to remove excess digits
    return round(Decimal(value).scaleb(-exponent).quantize(u)), u, exponent
```

Example:

```
for mean, err in [
    (123.45, 0.0012345),    # 123450 ± 1.2 (×10<sup>-3</sup>)
    (8165.666, 338.9741),   # 82 ± 3 (×10<sup>2</sup>)
]: 
    print("{} ± {} (×10<sup>{}</sup>)".format(*round_to_uncertainty(mean, err)))
```

The input `123.45`, `0.0012345` is reported as *123450 ± 1.2
  (×10<sup>-3</sup>)*.  And `8165.666`, `338.9741`
  translates to *82 ± 3 (×10<sup>2</sup>)* according to the rules from the current question.